# Create an array of object when scanner reads a text file

Tags: java, text-files, java.util.scanner

Using my Computer class [my computer class](http://ideone.com/vqTQmC) in the last project,I am supposed to write a program in Java that reads a file of computer data name computers.txt, and creates an array of Computer objects and so far I have this.

```
package project5;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class Project5 {


public static void main(String[] args){

    String[][] compArray = new String[50][50];
    String line = ":";
    String [] temp;

    Scanner file =null;
    try 
    {
     file = new Scanner(new File("computers.txt"));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not open file " + "computers.txt");
        System.exit(200);
    }

    int i = 0;
    while ((line = file.nextLine())!= null){ 
        temp = line.split(":"); 
        for (int j = 0; j<compArray[i].length; j++) {    
            compArray[i][j] = temp[j];
        }
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println(compArray[0][0]);
    }

}
```

Now I get an error. I did

```
System.out.println(compArray[0][0]);
```

to see if it was working but i got that error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
at project5.Project5.main(Project5.java:44)
```

the computers.txt file looks like this

```
Dell Computers Inc.:Inspiron 15 Touch:6:500:Intel Core i5:CD/DVD+-RW:Windows 8.1:649.99
Dell Computers Inc.:Inspiron 17:4:500:Intel Core i3:CD/DVD+-RW:Windows 7:549.99
Dell Computers Inc.:Alienware 18:16:1000:Intel Core i7:Dual Layer Blu-ray:Windows    7:2999.99
Acer Computers Inc.:Aspire AT3-600:6:2000:Intel Core i5:BlueRay:Windows 8:599.99
```

I need help with creating an array when reading the file

Comment: Yes you can use Scanner but its giving me an exception `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found` that's why I am using `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Im not sure why it gives that error

Comment: Are you getting same error? Have you tried my answer. Its working. Should I remove spring section from my post, if its useless for you?

Comment: i tired the code you modified from my code and it does work but I'm afraid it wont be accepted because of the uses of code I haven't learn yet

Comment: Ok just do one thing replace content of `while` loop only. Nothing else I have already mentioned where is the problem.

Comment: Could you help me with this? I'm not sure what is wrong with my while loop

Comment: Sure, you are using two dimensional array and `compArray[i].length` will return 50 wherever you have just 5 or 6 item in text file for each row after split. hence use `temp.lenght`. second you have to initialize `compArray[i] = new String[temp.length];` otherwise rest values will be `null`.

Comment: @Braj Can you show me how would I search in the array now? Say I need to display computers with a given CPU type

Comment: You know the index where CPU type is stored now just loop for all computers and find value at this index, compare it with your CPU type. I think it is index 1 use `for(int k=0;k<compArray.lenght;k++)if(compArray[k][1].equals(type));` just a not tested code

Answer (score 0):

You already have a `Computer` class (the one you linked to) that can hold all of these properties for a given "computer".

You know that each line in your file represents an individual computer. Therefore, each line can be represented by a `Computer` (the one you linked to).

You know how to parse these lines into an array of strings with `split()`, and that each element in that split array corresponds precisely to one of the properties of a "computer". This means that each line of the file can produce a `String[]` where each element of that `String[]` represents one of the properties of a computer (e.g. manufacturer is `compArray[0]`, model is `compArray[1]`, etc.).

You also know that you already have dynamic arrays such as [`ArrayList<Computer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) at your disposal.

Now it's just a matter of putting all this together:

1. Read each line from the file. For each line:
2. Split it as you are already doing.
3. Construct a new `Computer` and copy the split tokens to the appropriate properties.
4. Add that `Computer` to your dynamic `List<Computer>`.

Be sure to handle errors gracefully: What happens if you hit a blank line, or a line without the expected number of tokens in it?

You have all of the tools you need, so think about how you can put them together to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: In addition to it, the driver class(class with main) should have a different name. Computer class will just be a bean class (the one with properties).

As Jason mentioned, first come up with a model, visualize the sequence of steps and code.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because in your for-loop you iterate 50 times each time, that means j will increment to 50 by the end of the loop. Now the problem is in the line of code where you use temp[j]. Since temp will hold an array of strings returned by the split() method, based on your computers.txt file and your regex delimiter which is ":" colon, temp will hold an array of size 8, and when j variable increments to 8 you will get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8 since the temp isn't big enough, in other words temp doesn't have an index 8 or higher.

```
compArray[i][j] = temp[j]; // here is the problem.
```

Try this out

```
package project5;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class Project5 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[][] compArray = new String[50][];// instead of new String[50][50]
        String line = ":";
        String [] temp;

        Scanner file =null;
        try 
        {
            file = new Scanner(new File("computers.txt"));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not open file " + "computers.txt");
            System.exit(200);
        }

        int i = 0;
        while ( file.hasNext() ){ 
            line = file.nextLine() ;
            temp = line.split(":"); 
            compArray[i] = temp ; // Since you have an array of arrays you can put the return of your split method directly in your array
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println(compArray[0][0]) ;

        System.out.println(compArray[0][7]) ;
    }
}
```